# Formating GridView to display whole number from decimal

Tags: asp.net

Code below contain representation of decimal nuber as whole but when I have 0.00 value in DB I need to show as 0 but in this format GridView is rendering empty value. I am accepting only whole number as input to DB (*decimalFromDB*). The reason whay it is decimal is b/c in the future we might have data with decimals for now I just want display as a whole number and when is 0.00 display 0.

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="decimalFromDB" HeaderText="Number" 
        SortExpression="Number" DataFormatString="{0:####}" 
        NullDisplayText="0" />
```

I am getting this error from Stack Track when tring DataFormatString="{0:d}" or {0:D}

```
[FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.]
   System.Number.FormatDecimal(Decimal value, String format, NumberFormatInfo info) +0
   System.Decimal.ToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider) +39
   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +729
   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +107
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.FormatDataValue(Object dataValue, Boolean encode) +440
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e) +139
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +201
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3896
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Try `DataFormatString="{0:D}"`

Comment: Don't use `DataFormatString="{d}" or {D}` use `DataFormatString="{0:d}" or {0:D}`- include Zero and Colon

Comment: What is the datatype for the field in DB?

Comment: decimal(6,2) and allowing null

Comment: Strange. Ok how about trying "{0:N0}" or "{0:F0}" ?